# how redirect back after login and logout - laravel 5

Tags: ajax, redirect, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

Now after login or logout I am forwarded to the homepage.

in [this article](http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/03/11/changing-the-laravel-redirect-location-after-login/)  have read that
I can define redirection path in Auth Controller

```
protected $redirectPath = '/';
```

I can also change this line in Middleware RedirectIfAuthenticated.php:

```
return new RedirectResponse(url('/'));
```

But my goal is to

- either login by AJAX
- or, after login or logout, redirect back to the page where I have pressed the button.

Both answers highly appreciated.

Thx.

Answer (score 2):

To redirect to the previous page you can use `back()` like so:

```
return redirect()->back();
```

You can read more in the [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#redirects).

Comment: Nope. 
return redirect()->back(); just as Redirect::back() gives a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

How about using something like this ?

```
if(Session::get('redirect') == null) {
Session::flash('redirect', 'ok');
return redirect()->back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who have to redirect user back to the page where they clicked the  button for a protected page that redirected back to login. Here is my simple approach to it.

First on your nav, menu or whatever, your **href** value would be something like this:

```
<a href="{{auth::check() ? url('protected-page') : url('signin').'?redirect_to=post-request'}}"> Some Page </a>
```

What this simply do is, if your user is not logged in, its uses the lgin page as url, which simply cut off the need to redirect and adds the current page they are in which would be the page they would redirected back after login as a get param to the login url. Unlike using sessions to retrieve http_referer which would be wrong if user were redirected back to login due to validation error, this would stick around on your url.

Example of login url may be  `http://localhost:2008/signin?redirect_to=protected-page`

Then simply after login you would just check if get param **redirected_to** is available then redirect user back to that page or a default page if its not available as a get a param, probably your home or dashboard maybe, an example below might help.

```
$data = $request->all();
$referer =  $data['redirect_to'] ? url($data['redirect_to']) : url('/');
if($allowAccess) return redirect($referer);
```

I hope this helps someone!